# How can I improve the result of this non-linear optimization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear, constraint

Given a positive integer $d$ and some $0 < t < 1$ I would like to find a global minimum<sup>1</sup> for
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n d^2 \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \, x_k\right) + 8 d
$$
over $n \in \Bbb{Z}_{> 0}$ and $x_1,\dotsc,x_n \in [a,b]$ for some fixed $0 < a < b < 1$,
subject to the constraint
$$
1 - \prod_{k = 1}^n (1-x_k) \geq t.
$$
At this point I should probably mention that in my studies I had very little experience with numerical optimization, and that I am very new to Mathematica — I learned it while toying with this problem.

This is the code I have so far

```
a = Rationalize[0.1];
b = Rationalize[0.95];

(* Target function *)
fFactory[n_, d_] := Sum[d^2 * Tan[x[i] * Pi/2] + 8*d, {i, n}];

(* Constraints *)
gFactory[n_] := 1 - Product[(1 - x[i]), {i, n}];
cFactory[n_, t_] := Join[{g >= t}, Table[a <= x[i] <= b, {i, n}]];

vFactory[n_] := Array[x, n];
min[n_, d_, t_] := NMinimize[{fFactory[n, d], cFactory[n, t]}, vFactory[n]];
```

and it does seem to work. For example `min[3, 1, 0.85]` results in

```
{27.0299, {x[1] -> 0.612702, x[2] -> 0.612702, x[3] -> 0.1}}
```

However this isn't actually a global minimum. For example

```
gRoot[n_, t_] := 1 - Surd[1 - t, n];
expectedMin[n_, d_, t_] := n*genF[1, d] /. x[1] -> gRoot[n, t];
```

allows us to compute the value of the target function for

$$
x_1 = \dotsb = x_n = 1 - \sqrt[n]{1-t}
$$

and `expectedMin[3, 1, 0.85]` gives `26.7184`. I tried changing the `Method` option of `NMinimize` (as detailed [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html#217856200)), but all of `"NelderMead"`, `"DifferentialEvolution"`, `"SimulatedAnnealing"`, and `"RandomSearch"` gave the same result.

**Is there a way to tweak the options of `NMinimize`, or another function altogether, that would allow me to get a better result?**

<sup>[1] You can find more background on this problem from the related questions on [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549895/minimizing-the-non-linear-cost-of-successive-bernoulli-trials) and [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245489/cost-scaling-and-optimal-strategy-for-synthesis).</sup>

---

*Note:* I would actually *like an exact solution*, but from the documentation it seems that the algorithms used by `Minimize` don't work for this problem. Therefore I'd welcome some pointers on how to solve this problem using the Lagrange multipliers or the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions.

Comment: Aren't the `x[i]` undistinguished? They are probably all equal ...

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. Oddly enough, this is the first time I find myself on the receiving end of a comment template on an SE site... ;)

Comment: @belisariushassettled What do you mean precisely by "undistinguished"? If I understand you correctly yes, the problem is symmetric in the variables. I conjectured that the solution should be $x_1 = \dotsb = x_n = 1 - \sqrt[n]{1-t} =: p_n$ for the maximum $n$ such that $$n \left(d^2 \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \, p_n\right) + 8 d \right) < (n-1) \left(d^2 \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \, p_{n-1}\right) + 8 d \right)$$but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{a, b} = {1/10, 95/100};
(*Target function*)
v[n_] := Array[x, n]
ff[n_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := Sum[d^2*Tan[i*Pi/2] + 8*d, {i, v@n}]

(*Constraints*)
gf[n_?NumericQ] := (1 - Product[(1 - i), {i, v@n}])
cf[n_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := Join[{gf[n] >= t}, Thread[a <= v@n <= b]];

min[n_, d_, t_] := NMinimize[{ff[n, d], cf[n, t]}, v@n];
min[3, 1, 0.85]

(* {26.7184, {x[1] -> 0.468671, x[2] -> 0.468671, x[3] -> 0.468671}} *)
```

Comment: I feel stupid for not changing the constraints when I refactored my code... most importantly, though, while comparing your code with mine I noticed that re-evaluating a modified cell didn't update the functions I defined in it. Is this standard behaviour? If so, where is it documented?

Comment: By the way, I understand that you likely did this on purpose — sometimes dull-looking questions on MSE inspire a tiny bit of sadism in me, though I usually don't follow through with it — but you could have mentioned that the only significant thing you changed was the definition of the constraints. On the other hand, you taught me how to impose constraints on a function's arguments, of which I'm grateful.

Comment: @A.P. I started with your code, refactored a few things forth and back, and posted it when it worked. I didn't look back to see what I finally changed. I wasn't "hiding" it :)

Comment: @A.P. Re: **"I noticed that re-evaluating a modified cell didn't update the functions I defined in it. Is this standard behaviour?"** ... The answer is yes, unless you use exactly the same pattern for the function arguments. You can query all standing definitions for your function by using `DownValues[ function]` or `Information[function]`. Try `f[x_] := x^2;
f[x_?NumericQ] := x^3;
DownValues[f]`